# AIO Windows OS Installer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, usb, windows-installation

I repair laptops and PC and most of the time I need to repair/reinstall Windows. I prefer USB install as it is way faster then Optical Disk Method. But the thing is, you need to make a USB every time for different OS.

Is there a way to make an All In One ISO for Windows 10, 8.1, 8 & 7?

PS: I use the product key on their System or installed on their Windows.

Comment: There is no such "off-the-shelf" offering from Microsoft. You can get devices that you copy ISOs (literally any ISO you want) to and the device presents itself as an optical device - look up Zalman virtual CD ROM. They're USB 3.0 so work just as well as a USB you make. We have them and they're lifesavers if you forget or scratch a CD/DVD. It also keeps them in one, simple location (a built-in HDD). Secondly, what do you if you restore a PC that uses an OEM key? These can't simply be "extracted" and activated as they are preactivated and often only work with the OEM recovery media...

Comment: Zalman looks expensive... any alternative? For the OEM thing... honestly not my problem...

Comment: A quick look for "virtual ISO enclosures" comes up with StarTech and a couple of others, but this site isn't a product recommendation service; I was just saying that there are devices out there that do exactly what you want :)

Comment: Thanks. Let me google that. I was thinking what to google -.-'

Comment: I just found what i was looking for. It's easyBoot. This software is everything i needed!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for solution of this, Easy2Boot is the answer. I am using it and it's a godsend. I have a 64GB USB with all the ISOs in it. Windows XP till Windows 10 and major Linux flavors and a Hiren BootCD. It's not that easy to setup but it is neither that hard. I have put the link below. Have fun!

Regards!

[Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/)